# URL font in bibliography with Helvetica and BibLaTeX

Tags: fonts, biblatex, bibliographies, helvetica

I have the following example  with Helvetica font and BibLaTeX:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{foo2010,
author = "Doe, John",
journal = "Journal of Fun",
year = 2018,
title = "This is a title.",
url = {http://www.example.com/test/test}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Font
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

%% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=apa, sorting=nyt, backend=biber, doi=false, eprint=false, apamaxprtauth=999]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text.~\autocite{foo2010}

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

The document font is correctly set to Helvetica. However, the URL font in bibliography is some different serif font:

[image: broken URL font]

Is there a way to set the URL font to Helvetica as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` sets `\urlstyle{rm}`, but you want

```
\urlstyle{same}
```

Which gives

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, doi=false, eprint=false, apamaxprtauth=999]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
Some text.~\autocite{markey}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The URL in the example entry appears in sans-serif Helvetica now]

Note that `sorting=nyt` will not give you the exact sorting that the APA style needs, I suggest you remove it and let `biblatex-apa` specify the sorting on its own.